# Does `textPosition` parameter in `IDWriteTextLayout::HitTestTextPosition` means the utf-16 index or the `wchar_t` index

Tags: c++, direct2d, directwrite

The method `IDWriteTextLayout::HitTestTextPosition` takes the first parameter as `UINT32 textPosition` which the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritetextlayout-hittesttextposition) describe as:

> The text position used to get the pixel location.

But I can't fully understand the meaning of text position in this context. Does it mean the utf-16 index so I should use [CharNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-charnexta?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [CharPrev](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-charpreva?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to advance and decrease the index? Or does it mean the character (aka `wchar_t`) index which is 2 bytes on Windows?
Or does it mean the glyph index which I don't know what is it?

The text position is also in `DWRITE_GLYPH_RUN_DESCRIPTION` passed to `IDWriteTextRenderer::DrawGlyphRun`

Comment: It's the character index, so for unicode string `L"blah"`, 0 is b, 1 is l 2 is a and 3 is h.